# angular 2 hide if not in array

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following code to create a list of radio buttons.

```
<ul class="bankUl">
        <li *ngFor="let optie of vraag.opties; let i = index" class="{{i}}">
            <label class="image-radio">
                <input type="radio" name="fb" value="{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="_quizService.tmpBank" />
                <img [attr.src]="settings.imagePath + '/banken/' + optie.image" alt="{{optie.name}}">
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Now in my component I have an array like so

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4]
```

Now I want to make it so that every li class that is in the array gets hidden. but I dont know where to start. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: what you want to hide which element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ng-class` attribute

```
ng-class="{'class-name': ([1, 2, 3, 4].indexOf(i) > -1)}"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<li *ngIf="arr && arr.length>0">
```

[ngIf directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to destroy the object, just hide, and you are using Angular 2+, then:

```
[hidden]="!arr|| arr.length==0"
```